# Inequality with norm in Space $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, estimation

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded domain.

Let $v \in L^2(\Omega)$. It is possible to make an estimate of the type
$$\|v^2\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|v\|^k_{L^2(\Omega)}$$,
for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Using Holder's inequality, I'm able to get something like
$$\|v^2\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|v^3\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$
But what I really want is to get that square out of the norm. Thanks.

Comment: One should note that $\|u^2\|_{L^2}^2 = \|u\|_{L^4}^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A\subset \Omega$ satisfy
$0<|A|<1.$ For $u= |A|^{-1/4}1\hspace{-2.5pt}{\rm I}_A$ we have
$$\|u^2\|_2=1,\quad \|u\|_2=|A|^{1/4}<1$$
Hence for any  constant $k>0$ the inequality does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you obtain
$$
\| v \|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \int_\Omega v^2 dx \leq \|1\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|v^2\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = |\Omega|^{1/2} \|v^2\|_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
hence the inequality you wish for (*get that square out of the norm*) holds in the other direction with a constant depending on the size of the domain.